# How to use htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

</IfModule>
```

this is on my server (**mypage.com**) in .htaccess file.

How can i make:

1. If i open **here.mypage.com** then this redirect me to **mypage.com/here.html**
2. If i open **mypage.com/now** then this redirect me to **mypage.com/now/test.html**

My page is in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.If i open here.mypage.com then this redirect me to mypage.com/here.html

As long as **here.mypage.com** is the same document root the htaccess file is in, add:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^here\.mypage\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://mypage.com/here.html [R=301,L]
```

> 2.If i open mypage.com/now then this redirect me to mypage.com/now/test.html

Add:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mypage\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^now$ /now/test.html [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^now$ now/test.html
```

That's for the second one. The first one, you'll have to use your website cPanel (or similar) make a new subdomain, and point the subdomain to the main public_html folder, but we'll likely need more information about your server to give exact help.

EDIT:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^here.mypage.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/here.html [L]
```

That should do the subdomain.

Comment: i have subdomain, but now i want to redirect from subdomain to this address

Answer (score 1):

to redirect here.mypage.com to mypage.com/here.html, this will require more than to add a rule to the .htaccess (see => [Setting a subdomain](http://content.websitegear.com/article/subdomain_setup.htm)).

For the other one you can add :

```
RewriteRule ^now$ now/test.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Redirect 301 here.mypage.com mypage.com/here.html
Redirect 301 mypage.com/now mypage.com/now/test.html
```

Comment: Hostnames can't be matched in the regex of a `Redirect` directive